# Why does my website over-scrolls on safari on a mac?

Tags: html, safari

I am currently creating a website and when I look at it on safari, it heavily over-scrolls. This problem only occurs on safari on a mac (not on the iPhone). The website also shows fine when I use another browser such as Chrome.

I tried to add limitations to the CSS file like
`overscroll-behavior: none;`
and I checked the website with the developer tool where I found two div which are causing the problem but they don't seem to be part of my code and thus I don't know where they are generated Basically what I want, is that the page stops at the bottom of the footer.

[foto of overscroll beyond footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn64C.jpg)

[source of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en9sF.jpg)

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you have any screenshots? What do you mean by "over-scrolls"? What do you want to accomplish? What goes wrong with what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I tried to add limitations to the CSS file like `overscroll-behavior: none;` and I checked the website with the developer tool where I found two div which are causing the problem but they don't seem to be part of my code and thus I don't know where they are generated

Basically what I want, is that the page stops at the bottom of the footer.

Comment: Please add that clarification into the post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by wrapping the title image with a `<header> </header>` container and redirecting the CSS command from

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    
}

body > div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../Images/Background-1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
```

to this instead:

```
html, body, header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    
}

header > div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../Images/Background-1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```